# Using Office Ribbon in a Word Processor

Tags: user-interface, ms-office, ribbon

I heard Microsoft allows use of commercially available Office UI controls, with the exception of competing products, such as a word processor or spreadsheet app, etc.

How true is that?

Also, if it is not true, do you know of any *free* Ribbon controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at [Jensen Harris' blog entry about licensing the Office user interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/11/21/licensing-the-2007-microsoft-office-user-interface.aspx) which explains it in great detail. However I believe the relevant point here is:

> There's only one limitation: if you
>   are building a program which directly
>   competes with Word, Excel, PowerPoint,
>   Outlook, or Access (the Microsoft
>   applications with the new UI), you
>   can't obtain the royalty-free license.

Answer (score 1):

You can still build a word processor with a ribbon.  You just can't use *Microsoft's* ribbon.  There have been ribbon-like interfaces around for a lot longer than Office 2007 (the one that sticks in my mind most is the pallet in C++ Builder: very similar to a ribbon), so they definitely don't *own* the concept, if that's even possible.  I've seen a number of third-party or even open source ribbon controls.

Comment: But I do believe they have a patent on some part of it. It's possible that the C++ builder pallets could be used as prior art, but until then I'd be wary of copying the Office ribbon too closely.